# Angularjs- Why my DELETE request is going as Options?

Tags: angularjs, yii, cors, http-options-method

It was working perfectly but for some time i have stopped working on this project. I am sending a delete request to my server and it gives me this `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://abc.dev/users/users/18. (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed).(unknown)`

The API is written in Yii framework. I am using `CORS` extension for firefox , my `GET, POST` method working perfectly fine but my `DELETE` method seems like stuck.

My controller

```
$scope.delete = function (id)
    {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the user") === true) {
            $http({
                method: 'DELETE',
                url: 'http://abc.dev/users/users/' + id,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

            })
                    .success(function (data) {
                        $scope.singleuser = data;
                        console.log("function single user is processed");
                        $scope.user(); //call the function to reload
                    })
                    .error(function (data) {
                        console.log('error');
                    });


        }
```

My backend APi delete function

```
 public function actionDelete() {
    switch ($_GET['model']) {
        // Load the respective model
        case 'users':
            $model = User::model()->findByPk($_GET['id']);
            break;
        default:
            $this->_sendResponse(501, sprintf('Error: Mode <b>delete</b> is not implemented for model <b>%s</b>', $_GET['model']));
            Yii::app()->end();
    }
    // Was a model found? If not, raise an error
    if ($model === null)
        $this->_sendResponse(400, sprintf("Error: Didn't find any model <b>%s</b> with ID <b>%s</b>.", $_GET['model'], $_GET['id']));

    // Delete the model
    $num = $model->delete();
    if ($num > 0)
        $this->_sendResponse(200, $num);    //this is the only way to work with backbone
    else
        $this->_sendResponse(500, sprintf("Error: Couldn't delete model <b>%s</b> with ID <b>%s</b>.", $_GET['model'], $_GET['id']));
}
```

}

I am attaching an image of my network too.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a Cross-Origin Request most browser send an OPTION request before the actual request to check Access-Control-Allow-Origin. If the current domain is allow then the request is performed.

Comment: I have read a lot and tried different solutions but nothing went well. What should I do ?

Comment: handle OPTION on your server to return the right Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Answer (score 0):

This is a Server side issue. For security and to save on server load, web servers do not allow Cross origin requests by default.

Since you are working from localhost it is not allowing. It should work just fine from the live website. However if you want to allow Cross origin, you'll have to make changes in the NGINX/Apache .conf file on the server depending on what you are using.

eg: 
For Nginx you need to add few headers to the request

```
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Mx-ReqToken,X-Requested-With';
```

Comment: thanks for answering indeed it was a server side issue .

Answer (score 0):

It was a server side issue This document solved my problem `https://gist.github.com/sourcec0de/4237402` .